# customise THProgressView and increase uinavigationcontroller swipe back touch area

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, progress-bar

I want to customise [THProgressView](https://github.com/tiagomnh/THProgressView),

Please help me to remove animation, I need to show progress bar without animation using this example.
But it always animated.

```
CGRect rect = ...
THProgressView *progressView = [[THProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
progressView.borderTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[progressView setProgress:0.5f animated:YES]; // floating-point value between 0.0 and 1.0 //animated NO do nothing
```

**2)uinavigationcontroller swipe back touch area**

I want to know can i increate uinavigationcontroller swipe back touch area ? what its default size

Comment: This seems like a rather broad question since you want help with modifying a custom component - this might be a simple change or it could be very complicated. Perhaps you want to go through the THProgressView code and figure out which part does the animation and then ask a more focused question?

Comment: already i have added it in my code, but i want to know can i force it to stop animating?

Answer (score 0):

In your comment above, you said: "want to know can i force it to stop animating". According to the header file:

```
- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Since the `setProgress` method has an animated parameter, all you'd need to do is to pass `false` for that parameter to not have the component animate :)

Comment: It should be: `[progressView setProgress:0.5f animated:NO];` Your code above has `YES` for the `animated` parameter. Did you try changing it and running the code?

Comment: please check and run the sample code nothing happen

Comment: I believe what you are seeing as animation is the bar moving from one position to another - I'm not sure you can stop that since the bar has to move for the progress to change :) I have checked the code and I've also checked in the debugger and the animation code does not run when `animated` is set to `NO`

Comment: yes i want to stop animating the bar or moving from one position to another, can you customise the code?

Comment: I don't think you can since it is not actually animating - the new position is simply drawn in and your eye thinks it's animating since the bar changes size :) So it's not a code issue, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "directly show draw status"?